# Emergency mode на Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

При запуске Ubuntu происходит запуск emergency mode.
В Linux я новичек, поэтому прошу помочь и написать действия, которые необходимо выполнить, подробно.
[image: emergency mode При запуске ubuntu]

Comment: Советую вам задать текущий вопрос на площадке [Ask Ubuntii](https://askubuntu.com/) (на английском языке конечно же), там на него ответят быстрее т.к. площадка предназначена специально для таких вопросов.

Comment: Ну а `journalctl -xb` чё говорит-то?

Answer (score 0):

Так прям на экране написано
systemctl default набрать и enter нажать для загрузки в обычный режим